# "Knight rebus"-Decipher an encoded chess position

Tags: problems, retrograde-analysis

Here is a knight rebus. Each letter represents a different type of piece.
Uppercase letters are one color and lowercase letters are the other.

Determine the position. If possible, also determine the previous moves.

[image: Rebus]

**n** and **N** are kings and **h** is pawn. What is the rest?

Comment: Are you sure this is chess?

Comment: I'd say it isn't. At least not with standard rules.

Comment: @Peter What is the source of this problem? Is there a significance to the choice of letters used to encode the pieces?

Comment: @yrodro The source is XX all-Ukrainian tournament among young mathematicians. "Knight" is just a word of six different letters.

Comment: What's I, which side of the board is white, and which types of pieces are white.

Comment: @tony 1. Capital `I` represents the same piece as lowercase `i` but with different colour (namely, if `I` means "a black peace" then `i` means "a white peace" and vice versa). 2. As usual, white pieces move bottom up, black - top down. So the answer to your question is, I guess, bottom side of the board is white. 3. In the [answer](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/17894/knight-rebus-decipher-an-encoded-chess-position/17897#17897) below you can see that the pieces represented in capital letters are white.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Assume the board is in it's usual position (the bottom row is the first row) then this is the solution:

```
[FEN "1B6/8/1k6/R7/1n6/2K5/r6p/q1r1n3 - - - 0 1"]
```

and Black's last move was b2xc1R++.

<sub>I could write an explanation here about I came to this result, but it would essentially be copying @Maxwell's answer. I didn't use it, though.</sub>

Comment: Heh, I even thought about the possibility of multiple queens by promotion, but this is quite an interesting twist. Well done.

Comment: I assume `++` is a checkmate symbol, but is it really a checkmate? I think white king can run away to b3 or capture b4, or did I misunderstand something? Or is it "double check"?

Comment: @AndrewT. it's double-check. I'd use `#` for mate.

Comment: This can't be the solution. The King must have walked illegally into that double check. "i" is Bishop, "K" is knight. "g" is rook.

Comment: @LocalFluff Black's last move was with a pawn on b2, capturing a White piece on c1 and promoting to Rook. `i` can't be a Bishop, because a White Bishop on a5 would put the Black King in check as well.

Answer (score 7):

Yes indeed, n corresponds to king, as we need two kings of a different color to have a legal chess position.

Also, as you give, h = pawn, as otherwise we would have a pawn on the first or last rank, which would be illegal.

Consider i.
It cannot be a queen, as both kings would be in check.
It cannot be a knight, as the "i" on a2 would give check. There is no legal way where "knight a2 check" is the last move.
It cannot be a bishop, as the "I" on a5 would give check. There is no legal way where "bishop a5 check" is the last move.
Therefore, i = rook.

We see that the king on c3 is in check by the rook on c1. Therefore, g cannot be a queen or a bishop, because there is no legal way to obtain the resulting position.
So, g = knight.

The "K" on b8 should not give check to the king on b6.
Therefore, k = bishop and t = queen.

[However, the resulting position seems to be impossible to achieve too...
As far as I can see, the puzzle has no solution.]

**Edit: the resulting position is indeed possible**, see the answer of Glorfindel.

Comment: You're welcome and thank you for the question.

Answer (score 2):

This is a basic example of an orthodox retro form which has been taken to a new level over the last year by Ukrainian composer Andrey Frolkin and Canadian Jeff Coakley. I recently acquired a lovely landscape painting by Andrey's wife, Nina, which contains an embedded rebus by Andrey, who I bet authored the problem OP posted!

Although Maxwell's excellent proof relied at a couple of place on the edge of the board preventing retro-movement, this is not actually necessary. Shift all the pieces one square to the right (except for h on h2), and the problem remains sound (and in my opinion slightly superior :D )!

Proof: first count the pieces.

      `K N I G H T
Upper 1 1 1 0 0 0
Lower 0 1 2 2 1 1`

So N is king and by examining first and last ranks, H is pawn. Observe that whatever I represents, one instance is giving check to the enemy king. So any other checking unit implies a double check. So G is not a diagonal unit (bishop or queen), and K is not an orthogonal unit (rook or queen), since the resulting double checks are impossible. And I is not queen, or both kings would be in check!

So by elimination the queen is represented by T and we do have double check. So I can only be rook, and the position is achieved through promotion. Hence lower case is Black. G must be knight so by elimination K is bishop.

```
[title "Frolkin? version Laska rebus: solution"]
[fen "2B5/8/2k5/1R6/2n5/3K4/1r5p/1q1r1n2 w - - 0 1"]
```

and Black's last move was c2xd1=R++

Comment: So, what was the last move? That the white King walked illegally into that double check? "i" is Bishop, "K" is knight. "g" is rook

Comment: @LocalFluff: Thanks for the question. Last move was black pawn on c2 capturing something on d1 and promoting to rook check, also discovering check from queen. The solution would **have** to be something like this to allow white and black to be distinguished. If I,K&G are as you suggested, then both kings are in check: wKd3 from bQb1 and bKc6 from wBb5.